# VueTrix editor does not update when the model changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, trix

I am using Vue.js and VueTrix for my editor. I have discovered that when my data changes in the database the editor does not update.

Here is my code:

```
<div v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i">

    {{item.message}}

    <VueTrix class="trix-content responsive" id="clue" :inputId="item.id" v-model="item.message" placeholder="enter your content..."/>

</div>
```

I added `{{item.message}}` above the editor for testing purposes. When I change the content via a separate source, i.e. popup `{{item.message}}` changes as I type but the editor does not.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?